# using contains in java to check duplicates before adding to a two dim list

Tags: java, list, collections

I have the below code:

```
List<Check<String, String>> listAdd = new ArrayList<Check<String, String>>();
    for (list1<String, String> h : list1_a) {
        for (list2<String, String> s : list2_a) {
            if (condition) { 
                //if(!listAdd.contains(Check(h.getString(),s.getString())
                listAdd.add(new Check(h.getString(),s.getString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

im unable to understand how to use contains when there is a list within a list. Please help.Thanks

Comment: Is using the `Set` type out of the question?

Comment: @ChrisCooney im totally new to java and could not solve this effeciently

Comment: What @ChrisCooney means is that if the type of `listAdd` is `Set<Check<String,String>>` instead of `List<....>` then you can add without checking if it already exists; because it will add only if it does not already exist. Either ways, `class Check` needs to have well-behaved `equals` and `hashCode` methods, you might update the question with the code for those methods so others can help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (condition) {
   Check c = new Check(h.getString(), s.getString());
   if (!list.contains(c)) {
       list.add(c);
   }
}
```

Make sure you have `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods implemented in the `Check` class.

Another approach is to switch the `java.util.List` with some implementation of the `java.util.Set` interface. The `java.util.Set` subclasses support unique objects within, so you will no longer have to worry about whether some object is present is your collection or not.

Comment: Right ^^ contains() using the .equals() Method of his type. So you have to implemtent this in your Check.java

Answer (score 0):

try this in place of `//if(!listAdd.contains(Check(h.getString(),s.getString());`

```
if(!listAdd.contains(new Check(h.getString(),s.getString());
```